# How to upload a file in mvc3 using jquerymobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, jquery-mobile

Hi all i have create a small sample jquerymobile application in mvc3 i want upload a file in to data base using file upload control for this i have search on Inernet  some body says there is no file upload control in mobile application so,please help me is there any alternate solution for file upload in mvc3 jquerymobile ...please help me...

Comment: Hi all Any body help me please how to resolve to this

Comment: only the android mobile OS supports this, the iPhone/iPad do not support this feature.